# how to use aditional ip given with vps

Tags: linux, networking, centos

Got a vps today running centos 5. The company gave me 2 ip addy's. I pinged both from my current location and it seems the ping to the 'aditional ip' is much lower. I'm in shanghai and the vps is in los angeles. The round-trip ping to the aditional ip is 190ms (not bad for 6500miles away), whereas to the default ip it is over 300ms.

Anyone know how i can configure centos to use only the aditional ip? Also, do you think there's a reason for this big change in ping? The 2 ip's only vary by the very last digit and only bye one. Thanks.

Comment: Run a traceroute on both of them and compare. It could be as simple as a port on a switch somewhere along the route that is causing heavy latency.It could be more complicated. MTR will actually give you the best indication of where along the line the slowdown is.

Answer (score 1):

Can you provide output of `/sbin/ifconfig -a` on your machine? If you already have both IP addresses assigned to that box (which sounds like the case since you can ping them) you should be able to just bring down the interface using the slower IP. ie. `/sbin/ifconfig eth1 down`. Obviously you shouldn't take down any interfaces until you are sure you won't lock yourself out.